# How To Get The Proper Out Put As I need ?? My Logic For Line Text Split Not Fine?

Tags: java, string-parsing

I am trying to get only the service name from the data i am reading from buffer reader my data data is like this,

```
NetworkManager  0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
acpid           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
anacron         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
apmd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
atd             0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
auditd          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
autofs          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
avahi-daemon    0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
avahi-dnsconfd  0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
bluetooth       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
capi            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
conman          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
cpuspeed        0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
crond           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
cups            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
daemon.sh       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
dc_client       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
dc_server       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
dnsmasq         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
dund            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
firstboot       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:off   5:on    6:off
gpm             0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
haldaemon       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
hidd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
hplip           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
ip6tables       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
ipmi            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
iptables        0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
irda            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
irqbalance      0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
iscsi           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
iscsid          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
isdn            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
jexec           0:on    1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:on
kdump           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
kudzu           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
libvirt-guests  0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
libvirtd        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
lvm2-monitor    0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
mcstrans        0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
mdmonitor       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
mdmpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
messagebus      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
microcode_ctl   0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
multipathd      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
netconsole      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
netfs           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
netplugd        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
network         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
nfs             0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
nfslock         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
nscd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
ntpd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
pand            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
pcscd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
portmap         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
psacct          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
rawdevices      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rdisc           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
readahead_early 0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
readahead_later 0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:on    6:off
restorecond     0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rhnsd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rhsmcertd       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rpcgssd         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rpcidmapd       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rpcsvcgssd      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
saslauthd       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
sendmail        0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
setroubleshoot  0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
smartd          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
squid           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
sshd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
svnserve        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
syslog          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
tux             0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
vncserver       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
wdaemon         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
winbind         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
wpa_supplicant  0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
xend            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
xendomains      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
xfs             0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
xinetd          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
ypbind          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
yum-updatesd    0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off

xinetd based services:
        chargen-dgram:  off
        chargen-stream: off
        cvs:            off
        daytime-dgram:  off
        daytime-stream: off
        discard-dgram:  off
        discard-stream: off
        echo-dgram:     off
        echo-stream:    off
        eklogin:        off
        ekrb5-telnet:   off
        gssftp:         off
        klogin:         off
        krb5-telnet:    off
        kshell:         off
        rmcp:           off
        rsync:          off
        tcpmux-server:  off
        tftp:           off
        time-dgram:     off
        time-stream:    off
```

i want to get onlt servie name from this data these all are actually services of my linux system i am using this technique,

```
String text = "";
while((text = in.readLine()) != null) {
   text = text.split(" ")[0];    
   services.append(text+"\n");
   System.out.print(text+"\n");
}
```

actually i am reading data using buffer reader "in" is buffer reder and split it on space but i am getting this result from this code,

```
linuxNetworkManager
acpid
anacron
apmd
atd
auditd
autofs
avahi-daemon
avahi-dnsconfd
bluetooth
capi
conman
cpuspeed
crond
cups
daemon.sh
dc_client
dc_server
dnsmasq
dund
firstboot
gpm
haldaemon
hidd
hplip
httpd
ip6tables
ipmi
iptables
irda
irqbalance
iscsi
iscsid
isdn
jexec
kdump
kudzu
libvirt-guests
libvirtd
lvm2-monitor
mcstrans
mdmonitor
mdmpd
messagebus
microcode_ctl
multipathd
netconsole
netfs
netplugd
network
nfs
nfslock
nscd
ntpd
pand
pcscd
portmap
psacct
rawdevices
rdisc
readahead_early 0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
readahead_later 0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:on    6:off
restorecond
rhnsd
rhsmcertd
rpcgssd
rpcidmapd
rpcsvcgssd
saslauthd
sendmail
setroubleshoot
smartd
squid
sshd
svnserve
syslog
tux
vncserver
wdaemon
winbind
wpa_supplicant
xend
xendomains
xfs
xinetd
ypbind
yum-updatesd

xinetd
    chargen-dgram:
    chargen-stream: off
    cvs:
    daytime-dgram:
    daytime-stream: off
    discard-dgram:
    discard-stream: off
    echo-dgram:
    echo-stream:
    eklogin:
    ekrb5-telnet:
    gssftp:
    klogin:
    krb5-telnet:
    kshell:
    rmcp:
    rsync:
    tcpmux-server:
    tftp:
    time-dgram:
    time-stream:
```

why is there some service state also comming with the service name like

```
 "readahead_early   0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off"
 "chargen-stream:   off"
```

I want to get all these service name only

Comment: +1 for a well-structured question. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `text.substring(0, text.indexOf(" "));`
Basically for each line, just get everything from the first character till the first white-space.

Comment: by using this code it is printing all status too with the service name which i do not want :(

Comment: Write some code to figure out if those are tabs or white spaces after the service name? I suspect there is a mix of both in which case split on whitespace as ykaganovich suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your source is mixing tabs and spaces? Either make sure that spaces are used throughout, or do `text.split("\\s+")`

Comment: it is giving error incompatible type at this line you mentioned dabove

Comment: I think he means `text.split("\\s+")[0]`